# Sending variable to HTML from Flask

Tags: python, html, flask

In Flask I have a variable and I want to send this variable to html in this value `<input type="text" value="">`

**Flask Code:**

```
if not Class_Number.isdigit():
  flash("Wrote your class_id in int")
  Class_Number = 124124
  return redirect('/application', Class_Number=Class_Number, Name=Name, Phone_Number=Phone_Number, Reason=Reason, Special=Special)
  ...
```

**HTML Code:**

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="student_id">학번</label>
  <input type="text" id="student_id" name="student_id" value="{{ Class_Number }}" required>
  ...
```

What should I do?

Comment: Does `redirect()` accept and pass those parameters? https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/api/#flask.redirect I think all that is doing is setting a 302 header with the given route.

Comment: Could you show the code for the `/application` route that you are redirecting to?